# WPF C# XAML Animation

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

After I ran my animation I can't change FontSize of Textbox by code

Animation

```
da.From = textbox1.FontSize;
        da.To = 36.0;
        da.Duration = new TimeSpan(0);
        textbox1.BeginAnimation(FontSizeProperty, da);

        da.From = textbox1.Height;
        da.To = 48.0;
        da.Duration = new TimeSpan(0);
        textbox1.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, da);

        da.From = history.FontSize;
        da.To = 60.0;
        da.Duration = new TimeSpan(0);
        history.BeginAnimation(FontSizeProperty, da);

        da.From = history.Height;
        da.To = 68.0;
        da.Duration = new TimeSpan(0);
        history.BeginAnimation(HeightProperty, da);
```

textbox1.FontSize -= 1.0 do not work after anim;

Comment: do not insert images copy the code into your question

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: To stop the animation from overriding the property's current value, remove it, or give it a **FillBehavior** of **Stop**.